# How can I pipe a large C structure to Python directly?

Tags: python, c

I'm working on a MacOS system in Visual Studio Code. I'd like to be able to import a C structure filed with data from a C-file into a Python file, for that data to be plotted and handled.

I am working on a computation project where I am tracking pollution concentrations, which I calculate and store. The data is kept in a structure built like so:

```
struct ChemicalDemands{
    int time;
    double DO;
    double BOD;
};
```

For now, I've initialized the structure in main, computed data into it and tried to export its contents using stdout.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

struct ChemicalDemands{
    double DO;
    double BOD;
    int time;
};

int main(){
    // Create the structure we'll put data into 
    struct ChemicalDemands ChemicalDemands[3];  

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
        ChemicalDemands[i].DO=1.0;
        ChemicalDemands[i].BOD=1.0;
        ChemicalDemands[i].time=i;
    }
    // Export the data into a pipe
    fwrite(ChemicalDemands, sizeof(struct ChemicalDemands), 3, stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

The contents of the structure should therefore be something like this:

```
DO   BOD Time
1.0, 1.0, 1
1.0, 1.0, 2
1.0, 1.0, 3
```

I know I can export the data by writing it into a CSV file, which is what I've done for now, but I'd like to do it with pipes for automation.

On the Python side, I've tried reading the pipe as such:

```
import subprocess
import ctypes
import sys

#Define the equivalent C structure
 
class Results(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [("DO", ctypes.c_double),
                ("BOD", ctypes.c_double),
                ("time", ctypes.c_int)]
    
#Execute the compiled C file

result = subprocess.run(["./a.out"], capture_output=True)

if result.returncode != 0:
    print("Error:", result.stderr.decode())
    sys.exit(1)

buffer = result.stdout

# Determine the number of elements in the array (I've hardcoded it here for ease of debugging)
num_elements = 3

# Create a ctypes array from the buffer

results_array = (Results * num_elements).from_buffer_copy(buffer)

#Print the first line to check the elements are correctly selected
print(results_array[0].DO, results_array[0].BOD, results_array[0].time)
```

The results are totally false though. I get as an output:

```
6.9516022430103e-310 2.2615598355e-314 58081376
```

Any ideas with what I am doing wrong/need to do? Thank you!

Comment: To start: do you specifically know what **bytes** you are expecting to be in the C program's output? What bytes do you expect, and why? Do you know how to verify that from the Python program? What happens if you try that? Which is the problem: do you have the wrong bytes? Or are they being interpreted wrongly by the `ctypes.Structure`?

Comment: "I've tried sending the structure's data into a pipe using fwrite(ChemicalDemands, sizeof(struct ChemicalDemands), 60000, stdout);" - how did you choose the number `60000`? Did you verify that there is actually that much computed data to send? Can you make it work with a smaller amount of output, and verify it by hand?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel 60000 is the size of the array `struct ChemicalDemands ChemicalDemands[60000];`.

Comment: @AKX Just because OP declared an array of size 60000 in C does not mean that 60000 values have been assigned (in code that hasn't been shown to us and is probably mostly irrelevant) before the output took place. But more to the point, it's not feasible to debug with needlessly large data.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I used 60000 because that's how many 'rows' my structure has, like how long my simulation length is. It technically has 60000 rows of an int and two doubles. I guess this means 60000 *( 4+2*8) bytes so roughly 1.2 million bytes. I'd just learnt to put the number of rows though in the fwrite function. I'm guessing that's wrong?

Comment: Please just try a smaller example of the problem, so that you can validate what happens against your expectation (and *have* a concrete expectation), step by step. We expect this kind of debugging work here before a question is posted, because if it doesn't lead to an actual conceptual question, then it doesn't lead to a question that helps with the site's purpose of building a useful reference library. Other people can't benefit from your debugging unless they have the same problem and that problem can be clearly defined, described and explained.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I can try doing that to increase ease of use. Once I reduce the size though, if I can't fix the problem still, what is the recommended path to do? Post a new question and delete this one? Or edit the original question to a more reduced version of it?

Comment: Please *follow the debugging steps I have repeatedly laid out for you*, and *use the information that you gather* from that process. Depending on what happens, you may find that you no longer have a question to ask at all. But if you do, you should almost certainly [edit] this one.

Comment: That c structure may not be 4+2*8 bytes long.  The c compiler will add padding where it needs to to align types properly.    When you define the structure, put the largest types first, then the next largest,&etc. in order to minimize padding.

Comment: On the C side, try putting stdout in binary mode: `setmode(fileno(stdout), O_BINARY);`

Comment: @001, I'm working on MacBook in VSCode, so isn't stdout already in binary? I thought O_BINARY was only for Windows? Good suggestion though. I'll update my post to make it easier to answer as Karl Knetchel suggested.

Comment: @001, if the code isn't working for 3 items (see the edited post), I'd assume it's something else that's going wrong rather than the buffer size, probably the piping in itself.

Comment: Note that csv is a streaming format. There is no problem sending it via a pipe. Using raw bytes of the struct will just reduce the size.

Comment: @9769953 You're totally right, I went ahead and fixed it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Seems like a good fall back, but ideally I'd want to do this without adding extra files (even creating a CSV) into the mix...

Comment: I'm on macOS, M1, and your code example works fine for me. I'm not using VS code, and the standard Clang compiler (15.0.0). Python is 3.11.5.

Comment: @9769953 That's super weird! My Mac is an older version, intel chip, but runs fine. My Python is also on 3.11.5. When I compile my C, I use gcc myfile.c and run my output file with ./a.out. My GCC is up to date , though at 14.0.0 rather than your 15.0.0 (juste checked using brew). Did you compile in a different way to me?

Comment: @confusedcoder I'm suspecting there's a different alignment in the `ctypes` struct c.f. what you end up writing. Try `struct.unpack("@idd", ...)` instead?

Comment: @AKX So my data is being read into binary form (I printed it and checked) alright, but `struct.unpack("<idd", readinbinarydata)` gives me another issue. Since the struct being read in is multiline, the formatting string of 20 bytes isn't matching with the 78 bytes read in from binary. In case you're wondering, I used < rather than @ because MacOS is Little-endian (see [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)). Do you think it could be solved by slicing the data?

Comment: There is no gcc 14 released (unless in development, but that's unlikely to in Homebrw), so it looks like you're using (Apple's) Clang disguised as gcc; check with `gcc --version`. Also, try compiling with `-Wall -Wextra`; I don't get any warnings, so you shouldn't either. Final option I use is `-std=c11`.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's my output of `print(len(buffer), buffer.hex())`: `72 000000000000f03f000000000000f03f0000000001000000000000000000f03f000000000000f03f0100000001000000000000000000f03f000000000000f03f0200000001000000` (keep in mind I'm on a different architecture; and 72 bytes, no 78).

Comment: @9769953, I get 78 and `300a310a320a000000000000f03f000000000000f03f0000000001000000000000000000f03f000000000000f03f0100000001000000000000000000f03f000000000000f03f0200000000000000` running that. Putting it into a hex to txt converter is interesting. I get the 0;1;2 values associated with the time variable, but anything else is an unknown symbol. What encoding are you using? I have UTF-8 (which is the default I assume).

Comment: Encoding shouldn't matter: `buffer` is a bytestring; the printed values are just the hexadecimal values of each individual byte. So split them 2 by 2 by 2 etc to see the individual values; or use `' '.join(buffer.hex())` instead to see the individual bytes. There is definitely little use to interpret bytes that came from an array of a struct with doubles and int, as normal text (UTF-8 or ASCII, doesn't matter).

Comment: Just to double check: are you actually compiling the example in this question? Because, for example, the line `#include <stdio.h>` is still missing. If your code compiles without problems, that means you're not compiling the exact same code. In which case, there may be other things that are not the same, and there is no way for us to help you solve your problem.

Comment: @9769953 I updated both my compiler from Clang to gcc as you suggested and included <stdio.h>. The combination of both got it working and matched your results. Do you want to post this as answer so I can correctly credit you? Thank you for your help :)

Comment: "updated both my compiler from Clang to gcc as you suggested ": I didn't suggest that. I am actually using Clang. Unless you meant something else than what you stated.

Comment: If this fixed your issue, than there are probably a few things to note: - the compiler was likely not the issue; - use compiler flags for warnings and heed those warnings; - include <stdio.h>, because then `fwrite` and `stdout` are properly declared.

Comment: @9769953 What I mean is I managed to get my GCC from 14.0.0 to 15.0.0 like on your OS's specs

Comment: @9769953 Will definitely use `-Wall` way more in the future thanks to you. I wish I'd been taught it when I first was introduced to C, makes resolving issues way easier.

Comment: Again, there is no gcc 14 or 15. I take it you mean you possibly used `/usr/bin/gcc`, which is in fact `clang` acting somewhat as `gcc`. It doesn't really matter; you can now either use `/usr/bin/gcc`, `/usr/bin/clang` or `/opt/homebrew/bin/gcc` (wherever your Homebrew gcc is located): the inclusing of `<stdio.h>` is likely to have fixed your problem for all 3 compiler variants.

Comment: Why not build a DLL and use ctypes to call the C function directly instead of as a subprocess?

Comment: @MarkTolonen The snipet of code posted here is just a small part of the C code I have, and before I send the data back to Python 15ish other functions modify it, so I didn't find it very practical to call all of them through C-types. Your idea would probably better on a smaller scale to mine!

Comment: Just the entry point needs to be called with ctypes. Make your exe main (with a better name and parameters) and turn the exe into a DLL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include `<stdio.h>`: that way `fwrite` and `stdout` are properly declared.

As a tip: always include warning compiler flags, like `-Wall`, `-Wextra` and perhaps even `-Wpedantic`. Then, don't ignore the warnings, but try and understand them (some can be cryptic, but searching for the warning message can help a lot; and you learn from it, so it's not wated time!), and fix them.

Some will be essential to fix, some can be an easy code change to fix, and very few (read: essentially none) warnings can really be ignored.